# Noda Time Date Comparison

Tags: date, datetime, nodatime

I am new to `Noda Time` and I basically want to compare if a date has expired or not. In my case I have an object with the `date` it was created, represented by a `LocalDate` and the amount of `months` it's valid as an `int`, so I wanted to do a simple:

```
if ( Now > (dateCreated + validMonths) ) expired = true;
```

But I can't find in the Noda Time documentation the proper way to get the **Now Date** (they only show how to get the Now Time as `SystemClock.Instance.Now`) and the proper way to handle **time comparisons**.

For example if today is January 1st 2015 and the document was created in December 1st 2014, and it was valid for one month, today it expires its one month validity.

I miss methods such as `isBefore()` and `isAfter()` to compare dates and times. Simple overloads of the < > operators could also be very helpful.

---

EDIT:

1 - Sorry, there are `<` `>` operators to compare dates.

2 - I solve my problem using this code (not tested yet!):

```
...
LocalDate dateNow = this.clock.Now.InZone(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault()).LocalDateTime.Date;
LocalDate dateExpiration = DataASO.PlusMonths(validity);
return (dateNow < dateExpiration);
```

Comment: What are `dateCreated` and `validTime` here? If `dateCreated` is an `Instant` (i.e. it's the timestamp when something was created) and `validTime` is a duration (e.g. 24 hours) then it should be fine pretty much as is...

Comment: I am modeling dateCreated as a LocalDate and validTime as an integer representing the months this object is valid

Comment: In that case you should be using `dateCreated.PlusMonths(validTime)` to get the new `LocalDate`. Then see my answer...

Comment: Yes, this I could find in the documentation... But to get the current date I can see now in your answer... Any advices on simple and recommended ways to compare dates? Please see my question update, many thanks!

Comment: You can *compare* dates just with `>`, `>=` etc.

Comment: Oh nice :) ! I didn't saw it in the userguide...my bad I guess :P

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited my question and posted my final code, I didn't tested it yet, since now I am reading more about Noda Time and testing, but any comments if there is something wrong is most welcome :) and congrats on the amazing library!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the current date, you need to specify which time zone you're in. So given a clock and a time zone, you'd use:

```
LocalDate today = clock.Now.InZone(zone).Date;
```

While you *can* use `SystemClock.Instance`, it's generally better to inject an `IClock` into your code, so you can test it easily.

Note that in Noda Time 2.0 this will be simpler, using [`ZonedClock`](http://nodatime.org/unstable/api/html/T_NodaTime_ZonedClock.htm), where it will just be:

```
LocalDate today = zonedClock.GetCurrentDate();
```

... but of course you'll need to *create* a `ZonedClock` by combining an `IClock` and a `DateTimeZone`. The fundamentals are still the same, it's just a bit more convenient if you're using the same zone in multiple places. For example:

```
// These are IClock extension methods...
ZonedClock zonedClock = SystemClock.Instance.InTzdbSystemDefaultZone();

// Or...
ZonedClock zonedClock = SystemClock.Instance.InZone(specificZone);
```